# angular2 univesral - WARNING: your application is taking a long time to render the application

Tags: angular, angular2-universal

I am in dev mode doing simple testing using angular2 universal.

I get this message in the logs:

```
WARNING: your application is taking a long time to render the application
```

I concur....jeesh its takes several seconds to load.  How do I reslove?  I am running locally on my mac.

So from time it takes to make a requests is about 90 seconds.  My api server is then hit and I see 2 requests.  So its not the api server which is flask fyi.  If I reload the same request then fast.  Only new endpoint.

Here is my app component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterLink,Router,ActivatedRoute,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import { TestService } from '../service/test.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: __filename,
  directives: [RouterLink,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ TestService],
  styles: [],
  template: `
      {{state}}
      <br>
      {{city}}
      <br>
      {{report_list | json}}
  `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoading=true;
  state:string;
  city:string;
  report_list: any[] = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _TestService:TestService
              ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.map(params => params['state'])
            .subscribe(state => { this.state=state });
    this.route.params.map(params => params['city'])
            .subscribe(city => { this.city=city });

    this._TestService.getData(this.state,this.city)
                .subscribe(report_list => this.report_list = report_list,
                null,() => { this.isLoading = false; });
  }

}
```

Comment: FYI I was using chrome as my browser.  Tried on FF as fast.  No issue.  Still issues on chrome.  Why? Even safari is OK.  Whats the deal with chrome?